# Convert a multidimensional array (php)

Tags: php, arrays

im currently struggling with converting this array in PHP to a more simplified one. This is my array to start with stored in `$array`:

```
   [0] => Array
       (
           [name] => name-1
           [value] => xXX
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [name] => name-2
           [value] => YYY
       )
```

I would like to transfrom this array to this simplified one `$array_new`:

```
   [0] => Array
       (
           [name-1] => xXX
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [name-2] => YYY
       )
```

I sadly don't know were to start... Could somebody help me out?

Edit: After I converted the array via array_column() oder foreach loop I still cant get the right data with $array_new['name-2'];

Comment: One question: Why?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far or checked SO for similar questions.

Comment: Simply because I want to read the values easily? Or do you know a why how to get the value from name-1 with changing array keys?

Comment: Use `foreach` and create new array.

Comment: `array_column($array, 'value', 'name');` will works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array-column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to do that. The documentation said:

> array_column ( array $input , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = NULL ] ) : array

So do:

```
$first_names = array_column($array, 'value', 'name');
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/GMkld)

Comment: This transforms the array, but when I try to get the second name I will end up with the first name...

echo $first_names['name-1']; = xXX
echo $first_names['name-2']; = xXX

Comment: @Sigron - don't know why but added to my example and it works: https://3v4l.org/pKFJo

Comment: Not sure but the question says the output should be `[0] => Array   ( [name-1] => xXX   )` which has an extra level compared to this output `Array(  [name-1] => xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

## Question

Alright, this is a question I see a lot of beginners deal with.
Just be a little creative:

## Answer

```
//Let's get your old array:
$old = [
   0 => [
      'name' => 'name-1',
      'value' => 'xXX'
   ],
   1 => [
      'name' => 'name-2',
      'value' => 'YYY'
   ]
];

//Let's create an array where we will store the new data:
$result = [];

foreach($old as $new) { //Loop through
   $result[$new['name']] = $new['value']; //Store associatively with value as value
}

var_dump($result);
```

## Result:

```
Array[2] => [
   [name-1] => xXX,
   [name-2] => YYY
];
```

Comment: read php manual and check array_column()

Comment: @Aaron NoHuanKnows This transforms the array, but when I try to get the second name I will end up with the first name... echo $first_names['name-1']; = xXX echo $first_names['name-2']; = xXX –

Comment: Can you show me your full code on that aswell as the array?

Answer (score 0):

Using a foreach:

```
<?php

$items =
[
    [
        'plant' => 'fern',
        'colour' => 'green'
    ],
    [
        'plant' => 'juniper',
        'colour' => 'blue'
    ]
];

foreach($items as $item) {
    $output[][$item['plant']]=$item['colour'];
}
var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
    ["fern"]=>
    string(5) "green"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
    ["juniper"]=>
    string(4) "blue"
    }
}
```